# Retrieving the ID of a class selected input with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page on which I need multiple autocomplete plugin. I would like to use a class selector to init the autocomplete code. My issue is that within that code I must be able to select the ID of the triggered element. Is there a way to do that ?

```
//class selected input
$(".autocomplete-class").autocomplete({
    autoSelect: true,
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 200,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Country/Find", type: "GET", dataType: "json",
            data: { search: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    var test = $(this);
                    $(/* ID of the input */).val(function (index, value) {
                        return value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
                    })
                    $(/* ID of the input */).autocomplete("search");
                }
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item, value: item }
                }))
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: To me, the problem with this approach would seem to be that you would then only bind one data source to all your auto-completes.  Is that really what is intended? Or does each autocomplete need to have its own data source?

Comment: They all bind to the same source that's why I want to do it this way !